# Remove White (Enter) Spaces from Post Text (CSS)

Tags: css, post, formatting

I'm trying to format my website post using CSS to look like a fiction book. At the moment I'm using a paragraph class (p.custom-indent7 { text-indent:60px;} ) to create first-line indents on each paragraph, but the problem is that there is still the white "enter space" caused by each enter, making the text hard to read.

[Screenshot of the text formatting so far, with white spaces emphasized and slightly explained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chqzK.jpg)

I'd love to find a way to remove this space using CSS, too. I'm using WordPress and don't know enough about CMS systems to edit the actual structure of the program, so something front-end would be preferable :)

Also, because I format books for EPUB anyway using HTML I don't mind manually applying the text formatting to each paragraph. It would be nice if there's an easier over-all method, but doing it once for the site is then also useful for the final .epub and .mobi versions of the books.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since you're new, you might want to check how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The image you posted indicates that the paragraph-tag (still) has a margin, which causes the spaces at the top and bottom. But to be sure, we need some code to check.

Comment: You probably just want to eliminate the margins of the paragraph elements …

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael and Misorude! I didn't even know what I'm looking for, but your questions helped me find the research I needed. I changed my CSS class formatting to:

```
p.custom-indent7 { 
    text-indent:60px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

And it now formats the WordPress post like a fiction book, which is exactly what I wanted. Sorry that I didn't know more about coding, I really appreciate both your help :)